# How to assign a task to a particular logical core?

Tags: logical-processor

A calculation intensive program is invoked from the command terminal.   A set of calculations are required by calling said program several time in one or more batch files, thus each call could be run in parallel.  Assume the fundamental terminal syntax is:

> simulate.exe input.txt

Assume the Windows 10 PC has an [i7-3770 CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/65719/intel-core-i73770-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz/specifications.html) with 4 physical cores: each physical core provides two logical cores for a total of 8 logical cores.   6 batch files are generated: one batch file for each logical core.  The goal is to ensure that 6 batch files are run on 3 physical cores with the 4th core exclusively available to Windows.  For example `go_CPU1.bat` would execute:

```
 simulate.exe input1.txt
 simulate.exe input2.txt
 simulate.exe input3.txt
 ...
 simulate.exe input100.txt
```

Is there command line syntax to assign the simulation to a particular enumerated logical core?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `start` command coupled with the `affinity` mask to control which core(s) you want the process isolated to.

> START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
> [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
> [/NODE ] [/AFFINITY ] [/WAIT] [/B]
> [command/program] [parameters]

> ```
> AFFINITY    Specifies the processor affinity mask as a hexadecimal number.
>             The process is restricted to running on these processors.
>             The affinity mask is interpreted differently when /AFFINITY and
>             /NODE are combined.  Specify the affinity mask as if the NUMA
>             node's processor mask is right shifted to begin at bit zero.
>             The process is restricted to running on those processors in
>             common between the specified affinity mask and the NUMA node.
>             If no processors are in common, the process is restricted to
>             running on the specified NUMA node.
> ```

***ALL masks are done in hexadecimal.***
You can use the Windows calculator in programmer mode to figure it out.  I show you how to do that below.

For instance, hex value 3A translates to `00111010`
This is 0 based meaning proc #1 is actually #0
Also note that the binary reads backwards

***These are how the procs are laid out***
Binary:   00111010  <-HEX 3A
Reality:  76***543***2***1***0  <-Procs in reverse order

3A means DONT USE 0,2,6,7 -- USE 1,3,4,5

> "start /AFFINITY 3A Notepad.exe" produces this:

[image: start /AFFINITY 3A Notepad.exe]

***What a pain in the butt.. right? ..***
Don't sweat it! The handy dandy Windows Calculator can help us out.

1. Open calc.exe and change it to Programmer mode.
2. Click the funky monkey second dotted "bit toggling keypad" (shown in screen shot).
3. Click on the BIN thingamajigger on the left.
4. Type in your binary just like you want the procs used.

For your viewing pleasure, I have included a screen shot with hints.

[image: Windows Calc.exe showing programmer mode]

```
  @echo off
  start /AFFINITY 3A notepad.exe
  REM Why on earth would notepad need so many procs?
  REM Who knows.. ?
```

Comment: Useful reference : https://ss64.com/nt/start.html (search for `affinity`).

Comment: Please consider posting an example based on the original posting?   Assume a batch file named `go_CPU1.bat` Thank you

Comment: I went with notepad.exe instead.  This answer is intended to help everyone that needs to know how this works.  You can use `start /AFFINITY 1 simulate.exe input1.txt` `start /AFFINITY 2 simulate.exe input2.txt` `start /AFFINITY 4 simulate.exe input3.txt` to use cores 1,2,3 independently.  ***Remember, the 1, 2, 4 are HEX as in 0x01, 0x02, and 0x04 which translate to 00000001, 000000010, and 00000100.***